# Hadoop : Tools for visualizing key value data and files for development

Tags: java, hadoop, key-value, file-browser

**Are there any simple, easily launched java tools for visualizing key/value data from map reduce job directories ?**

Specifically i want to browse a 20-job map reduce workflow , cliicking on individual files and looking at the data, and maybe even see a histogram of file sizes.

- There are some caveats here, for example -

  - Some files have serialized data (not just text)
  - Obviously, this system would probably be silly to use at "cloud scale" , rather its a dev tool.

**Nevertheless, such a tool would be useful developing and locally debugging large, connected m/r pipelines.**

This is for development purposes (im not trying to visualize the distributed key/value hadoop data in a real cluster).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [KarmaSphere Studio](http://karmasphere.com/Products-Information/test-community.html?mainid=349)

> Monitor Job Execution Step-by-Step
>    - Workflow with Results: Shows the resulting output at each step of the MapReduce job.
>    - Hadoop Logs from the Desktop: Accesses Hadoop logs easily from the desktop.
>    - Job Failure Options: Allows the specification of job failure options such as automatic invocation of a specified script upon job failure for EMR.

Comment: Thanks - looks like a heavy weight utility... Any specifics on how could I use karma sphere to solve my specific issues?

Comment: sorry, but I realized that karmasphere doesn't do what I needed , although it seems to.  It is only capable of monitoring and browsing job data when you execute the job in k-sphere.

Comment: I  want a tool that is more stateless and modular, I think kaashpere is restrictive.  I want a lightweight jar file that is modular and extensible - I have thrift data that is binary serialized, etc.... Seems like karma showers paradigm Is better for starting a new code base than debugging an existing one .